# How does GitHub Actions Workflow resolve minor versions of an actions?

Tags: github, github-actions

In GitHub job workflows a github action is typically referenced by version for example `actions/checkout@v3`

```
jobs:
  build:
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
```

when I visit the Action's [releases page](https://github.com/actions/checkout/releases) I see that the current version is 3.2.0.

**Questions:**

- When referencing an action using the `actions/checkout@v3` does it use the most recent minor version when the action when the workflow is executed.
- If I run the above job will it use version 3.0.0 of the action or version 3.2.0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It uses the *explicitly specified* version or tag. For a public action the format is `{owner}/{repo}@{ref}` in which `{ref}` can be a Git tag, branch or SHA. See the relevant [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsuses) for more details.

Whether a GitHub Action offers major tags (e.g. `v3`) is at the discretion of the action maintainers. If it is offered, usually the major tag is force pushed to point to the same commit as the new minor version tag when a new minor version is released.

For example, [`actions/checkout`](https://github.com/actions/checkout) has a helper workflow (see [*update-main-version*](https://github.com/actions/checkout/blob/v3/.github/workflows/update-main-version.yml)) which can be manually triggered to do this. Many other actions use [`actions/publish-action`](https://github.com/actions/publish-action) despite currently being in alpha development and GitHub does *"[...] not recommend this action for public or production usage while it is still in development."* The purpose is to update the major version tag or create a new one if it does not exist yet.